# SWT Dialog does not display correctly

Tags: user-interface, windows-7, dialog, swt

When opening a new dialog, while its loading, you click couple of times on parent shell, apparently the new dialog does not display correctly.
Please see the example below:

### Examples

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZovxE.png (eclipse IDE example)
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zVar.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/u86b9.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGaAr.png

Initially I encountered the problem in december 2014, and back then also reported by vaious in house devlopers which were using different development systems and then same problem has been reported by our several customers.

This behavior can be reproduced using following environment:

> - Windows Version: 7 Pro 64 Bit - 6.1.7601
> - Java Version: RE 1.8.0_121_b13
> - SWT Versions
>
>   - 3.8.2
>   - 4.6.2
>   - 4.7M6
>   - I20170319-2000

I could only reproduce the problem on Windows 7 with the windows basic theme/design/style (not with classic or aero). 
On windows 10 its not reproducible.

## reproduce

### code to reproduce

```
package test;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.RowLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = createShell(display);
        createButton(shell);
        shell.open();
        eventLoop(display, shell);
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static Shell createShell(Display display) {
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new RowLayout());
        shell.setSize(500, 200);
        return shell;
    }

    private static void createButton(final Shell shell) {
        final Button openDialog = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        openDialog.setText("Click here to open Dialog ...");
        openDialog.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                TestDialog inputDialog = new TestDialog(shell);
                inputDialog.open();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void eventLoop(Display display, final Shell shell) {
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}

class TestDialog extends Dialog {

    public TestDialog(Shell parent) {
        super(parent, SWT.DIALOG_TRIM | SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.MIN | SWT.MAX | SWT.RESIZE);
        setText("Dialog");
    }

    public void open() {
        Shell shell = new Shell(getParent(), getStyle());
        shell.setText(getText());
        createContents(shell);
        shell.pack();
        initializeBounds(shell);
        shell.open();
        eventLoop(shell);
    }

    private void createContents(final Shell shell) {
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));

        Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        label.setText("Some Label text ...");

        final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        text.setLayoutData(data);

        createCloseButton(shell);

        /* time for the user to create the misbehavior */
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCloseButton(final Shell shell) {
        Button closeButton = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        closeButton.setText("Close");
        GridData data = new GridData(GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL);
        closeButton.setLayoutData(data);
        closeButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
                shell.close();
            }
        });
        shell.setDefaultButton(closeButton);
    }

    private void initializeBounds(Shell shell) {
        Rectangle bounds = shell.getBounds();
        Rectangle parentBounds = getParent().getBounds();
        bounds.x = parentBounds.x;
        bounds.y = parentBounds.y;
        shell.setBounds(bounds);
    }

    private void eventLoop(Shell shell) {
        Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### steps to reproduce

1. Start the application

   - it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMJ9e.png
2. Click on the button.
3. Keep continuously clicking on right bottom corner of the parent shell (avoid hitting the new opening dialog), till mouse cursor changes to wait icon and parent shell changes its color.

   - it should look as following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Ikp.png
4. Wait until the new dialog appears.

   - it looks likes as following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTDgQ.png (incorrectly displayed)
   - instead: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHVjn.png (correctly displayed)

#### steps to reproduce done in video

- https://youtu.be/7ukhloCPf0k

When you mouse hover some of the UI elements (the originally not correctly drawn), you can notice some of them to be get painted (e.g. table rows).

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkMKn.png (before opening the dialog)
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXIKc.png (after opening the dialog)
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/25M7S.jpg (after mouse over)

Even calling `Shell.update()` or `Shell.redraw()` after the Dialog opened does not fix it.

In Windows Performance Options -> Visual Effects -> disable "Use visual styles on windows and buttons" is the only option I found which provides a workaround,
which seems to be the same as changing the design/theme/style to classic.

- https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1908-visual-effects-settings-change.html (How to Change Windows Visual Effects)

In the end, I have following questions:
Is it a SWT or Windows problem?
Is there any related topic in bug entries for Windows or in Eclipse Bugzilla?
Is there someone else who experienced the same problem? please share the experience.
Is there any settings in SWT or Windows which could affect its look n feel and fix the problem?

Comment: Doing a `Thread.sleep` in the SWT UI thread is guaranteed to cause problems since it will stop the thread calling `display.readAndDispatch` which is vital to the correct operation on SWT.

Comment: @greg-449 The `Thread.sleep` just simulates a unavoidable longer operation on the UI thread.
It also can happen for example between 
`TestDialog inputDialog = new TestDialog(shell);` 
and 
`inputDialog.open();`

The point is the UI does not catch up in the describe circumstance after the operation is finished and lead to the described result.
Is there a way to force a correct draw of the dialog?

Comment: You must not do **any** long operations on the UI thread - you **must** do them in a background thread. Failing to call `readAndDispatch` in a timely manner will always cause problems.

Comment: I know that `Display.readAndDispatch()` is needed for a responsive UI (in this case I do not care for). 
I did not know that you are not allowed to do any long operations on the UI thread what seems strange to me.
@greg-449 Please share your source in which this is specified.

Comment: Pretty much any description of SWT will tell you this. The first thing that comes to hand is the [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html) on Eclipse background tasks (Eclipse is just a big SWT app). See section 2.1 'Main thread'. As I said the requirement is that `readAndDispatch` must be called constantly, any delay in calling this will cause problems.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you

"If you perform a long running operation in the main thread, the application does not respond to user interaction during the execution time of this operation.

Blocking the user interaction is considered a bad practice. Therefore it is important to perform all long running operations in a separate thread."

Bad practice does not mean it is not allowed. 
I understand that a not responsive UI is bad practice.
I still think it is possible that this could be a bug in Windows 7 or SWT.

Comment: @MarkRösler It's not a bug. If the UI thread is tied up with whatever your long-running task is, then it can't also update the UI like it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the end, I have following questions: Is it a SWT or Windows problem?

Neither. As others have mentioned, you certainly should not tie up the UI thread with any long-running task. That work belongs in a background thread.

In regards to using a background thread, there are several ways you could go about this depending on how you want your `Dialog` to behave.

One option would be to kick off the background thread and then open the dialog when the task is done. I personally don't care for this because while the task is running, a user may think that nothing is happening.

Another option would be to open the dialog but display a "Loading" message, or something to that effect to give meaningful feedback and let a user know that the application isn't frozen (like how it looks/responds in your example).

The strategy would be to:

1. Create the dialog
2. Start the long task on a background thread and register a callback
3. Open the dialog with a "Loading" message
4. When the task is complete, the dialog will be updated from the callback

---

If you search around a bit on using `Executors`, you should find some far better examples and detail on how to use them.

Here's a brief example to illustrate what that might look like:
*(Note: There are definitely a few issues with this code, but for the sake of brevity and illustrating the point I opted for a slightly naive solution. Also there are Java 8-esque ways that would be a bit shorter, but again, this illustrates the idea behind using a background thread; the same concepts apply)*

Given a `Callable` (or `Runnable` if you don't need a return value),

```
public class LongTask implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

You can use the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class to create a thread pool, and then an [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to submit the `Callable` for execution. Then, using `Futures.addCallback()`, you can register a callback which will execute one of two methods depending on whether the task was successful or failed.

```
final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
final ListeningExecutorService executorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(threadPool);
final ListenableFuture<String> future = executorService.submit(new LongTask());
Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback(){...});
```

*In this case I used the Google Guava implementation [`ListeningExecutorService`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/ListeningExecutorService.html) which makes things a bit cleaner and simpler, in my opinion. But again, you may not even need this if you opt for a more "Java 8" approach.*

As for the callback, when the task is successful, we update the `Dialog` with the results. If it fails, we can update it with something to indicate failure:

```
public static class DialogCallback implements FutureCallback<String> {

    private final MyDialog dialog;

    public DialogCallback(final MyDialog dialog) {
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(final String result) {
        dialog.getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.setStatus(result);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(final Throwable t) {
        dialog.getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.setStatus("Failure");
            }
        });
    }

}
```

In this case I opted for the `Callable` to return a `String`, thus the `FutureCallback` should be parameterized with `String`. You may want to use some other class that you created, which will work just as well.

Notice that we use the `Display.asyncExec()` method to ensure that the code which updates the UI runs on the UI thread, because the callback may execute on the background thread.

Like I said, there are still a few issues here, including what happens when you click the cancel button before the task completes, etc. But hopefully this helps illustrate an approach for handling long-running background tasks without blocking the UI thread.

---

Full example code:

```
public class DialogTaskExample {

    private final Display display;
    private final Shell shell;
    private final ListeningExecutorService executorService;

    public DialogTaskExample() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        executorService = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1));

        final Button button = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        button.setText("Start");
        button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(final SelectionEvent e) {
                final MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog(shell);
                dialog.setBlockOnOpen(false);
                dialog.open();
                dialog.setStatus("Doing stuff...");

                final ListenableFuture<String> future = executorService.submit(new LongTask());
                Futures.addCallback(future, new DialogCallback(dialog));
            }
        });
    }

    public void run() {
        shell.setSize(200, 200);
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
        display.dispose();
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        new DialogTaskExample().run();
    }

    public static class DialogCallback implements FutureCallback<String> {

        private final MyDialog dialog;

        public DialogCallback(final MyDialog dialog) {
            this.dialog = dialog;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final String result) {
            dialog.getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.setStatus(result);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(final Throwable t) {
            dialog.getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialog.setStatus("Failure");
                }
            });
        }

    }

    public static class LongTask implements Callable<String> {

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
            return "Hello, World!";
        }

    }

    public static class MyDialog extends Dialog {

        private Composite baseComposite;
        private Label label;

        /**
         * @param parentShell
         */
        protected MyDialog(final Shell parentShell) {
            super(parentShell);
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        @Override
        protected Control createDialogArea(final Composite parent) {
            baseComposite = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
            label = new Label(baseComposite, SWT.NONE);
            return baseComposite;
        }

        public void setStatus(final String text) {
            label.setText(text);
            baseComposite.layout();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be straight forward, only that you are making the main Thread sleep for 15secs hence the delay. If not required remove  the sleep or reduce the time for sleep to 5secs or so.

Comment: The purpose of the sleep is to simulate a unavoidable longer operation on the ui thread during opening of a dialog.
In the code example case the sleep enables the tester to click on the parent shell while the dialog is opening.
I wanted to give a minimal code example to ensure it is not the code which cause the problem.
Is it the wrong way to handle such a case?

Comment: You are already using modality that is there for this purpose or put the dialog in new Thread and check.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. Can you give me a code example?

Comment: Can u instead send me a document or so of the requirement.

Comment: No I cannot. What do you mean by "put the dialog in a new Thread"? Do you mean an other main/ui thread?